# SQL Syntax error phpmyadmin #1064

Tags: mysql

i have been trying to figure out what is wrong but could not find the problem.

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064

```
CREATE TABLE Show
(
    Show_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FOREIGN KEY (cinema_id) REFERENCES cinema(cinema_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (show_time_id) REFERENCES show_time(show_time_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (show_day_id) REFERENCES show_day(show_day_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (show_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreign key` constraint is applied to an *already declared* column.  It doesn't do the declaration.  So, you need to declare the columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Shows (
    Show_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Cinema_id int,
    Movie_id int,
    Show_Time_id int,
    Show_Day_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (cinema_id) REFERENCES cinema(cinema_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (show_time_id) REFERENCES show_time(show_time_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (show_day_id) REFERENCES show_day(show_day_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (show_id)
);
```

Note that `show` is a reserved word in MySQL, so I changed the table name to `shows`.  I typically use plurals for table names anyway, because they are collections of things.

Comment: it didnt solve it... it keeps showing me the same error. this is what it says"'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near Show
(
    Show_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Cinema_id int,
    Movie' at line 1 "

Comment: the word SHOW is a reserved word as noted above, Re-name your table.